# What does "ethnic X", where X is the people of a country, mean?

Tags: word-usage

In http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-pacific-15263826 there is the phrase "ethnic Russian". Will you please tell me what does it mean? (I know what the word "ethnic" means)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means those Russians who denote their origin by birth or descent rather than by present nationality.

OxfordDictionaries defines it

> [ethnic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ethnic) - *Denoting origin by birth or descent rather than by present nationality*

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much. But then how to say those who are of present nationality?

Comment: Maybe, migrated or settled recently.

Comment: Indeed, sounds great.